# How can I display an RTSP stream on a web page with client-side decoding?

Tags: encoding, rtsp, rtsp-client, rtsp-server

I'm trying to find a solution to display an RTSP stream on a web page. I want to perform client-side decoding of the RTSP stream to minimize server-side processing and reduce latency. What are some recommended approaches or technologies that I can use to achieve this?

I've already tried using OpenCV to display the stream on the client side, but now I want to explore options for embedding the stream in an HTML page. Are there any JavaScript libraries or frameworks that support RTSP decoding and can be used in a web browser? Additionally, what are the best practices for handling RTSP streams in terms of security and performance?

Any guidance, code examples, or references to relevant resources would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].
Moreover, clarify your specific problem or provide additional details
 to highlight exactly what you need.  As currently written,
 it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.